# How to add local roadmap to Google map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

I live in rural areas, my town doesn't had roads in google maps. How can I add my own or create it. Where to start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good place to start is [Google Map Maker](http://www.google.com/mapmaker), which allows you to edit roads and other features in Google Maps. From your user profile, it looks likes you are in Indonesia, and it looks like Map Maker is not available there yet according to [this page](http://maps.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=155415). So Google Map Maker is the answer to your general question, but unfortunately may not help you specifically.

Your other option is to [create your own tiles](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/overlays.html#CustomMapTiles), but that will be more cumbersome and require both a way to create the tiles and a way to serve the tiles.